# Qt c++ create object from QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt

Hi I'm trying to save entered text from multiple QTextEdit widgets into an object called film of type Film but I don't know how to do it. titleEdit,durationEdit, directorEdit and relDateEdit are all of type QTextEdit. Here is the constructor for Film.

```
Film::Film(QString t,int dur,QString dir,QDate r):                                                                                                                                       
m_title(t),m_duration(dur),m_director(dir),m_releaseDate(r){
}
```

And the function that is supposed to take the text entered into the various QTextEdit's and create a film object with the values. Am I on the right track trying to convert the QStrings to plaintext? What do I do with the int? the obtainFilmData function is supposed to save the state of a Film object to a file.

```
void FilmInput::saveFilm(){
    Film film(titleEdit->toPlainText()),durationEdit ,directorEdit->copy(),
    relDateEdit->copy());
    obtainFilmData(film);
}
```

Comment: You'll be better off with QLineEdit for single-line text and QSpinBox for integer value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming here, that all of your input widgets are `QTextEdits`.
You can [convert QString objects to int](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstring.html#toInt). You can do something like this to create your film object:

```
Film film(titleEdit->toPlainText(), durationEdit->toPlainText().toInt(),
directorEdit->toPlainText(),
QDate::fromString(relDateEdit->toPlainText()), "dd/MM/YYYY"));
```

Read [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qdate.html#fromString-2) to find out about the date formats used in the `QDate::fromString(const QString & string, const QString & format)` function.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have an extra parenthesis in here

```
Film film(titleEdit->toPlainText()**)**,durationEdit ,directorEdit->copy(),
relDateEdit->copy());
```

There shouldn't be a problem with your constructor either.

Comment: ok took out the parenthesis but that is not the problem, durationEdit is not even being assigned anything and I don't know what to assign it to do?